# Why Windows Task Manager and VMMap show different memory usage?

Tags: windows, memory-management, profiling, out-of-memory, vmmap

I am analyzing server application, written in Delphi7, running on Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition SP2. Need to check when it goes out of memory.
The memory usage displayed in Task manager and that in SysInternals VMMap are different. Why?
Any suggestions, links?
Task Manager: "Mem Usage" is Working Set according do Help and "VM Size" is Committed memory.

So that in Task manager I have Committed memory 801 MB, but in VMMap 877 - what is the difference of 76 MB?

[image: Mem Usage: Win Task Manager vs VMMap]

Comment: I'm also curious. VMMap even shows a larger private WS for calc.exe than task manager does.

Comment: Your private data seems massive - any idea what caused that (looking for an answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020667/what-does-private-data-define-in-vmmap)?

Comment: I'd recommend to watch Mark Russinovich's talk "Mysteries of Memory Management Revealed" - https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405 
He mentioned some incompatibilities between Task Manager on different Windows and VMMap.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Because they are measuring slightly different things, or they are measuring the same thing at different points in time (when did you refresh VMMap vs Task Manager?)

Task manager probably isn't a good place to start if you are going to be counting things at the byte level. You might find performance monitor more fruitful. VMMap is also very useful for an overall look at things.

FWIW Working set is not a particularly useful value for tracking "out of memory".